# Custom Post Types and template_redirect

Tags: custom-post-types, template-redirect

I have two custom post types (e.g. post_type_1 and post_type_2) that I would like to redirect to independent templates (single-post_type_1.php and single-post_type_2.php) to handle their display. I don't want to put the display templates in the theme folder as I want them self-contained in their respective plugin folders.

How can I have each of them register a template_redirect hook without affecting the other? Or should I be using a different technique?

Currently, I'm doing this in Plugin 1:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_1' );
function template_redirect_1() {
    global $wp_query;
    global $wp;

    if ( $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'post_type_1' ) {

        if ( have_posts() )
        {
            include( PATH_TO_PLUGIN_1 . '/views/single-post_type_1.php' );
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        }

    }
}
```

And this in Plugin 2:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_2' );
function template_redirect_2() {
    global $wp_query;
    global $wp;

    if ( $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'post_type_2' ) {

        if ( have_posts() )
        {
            include( PATH_TO_PLUGIN_2 . '/views/single-post_type_2.php' );
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            $wp_query->is_404 = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Once I register plugin 2's template_redirect hook, plugin 1's no longer works.

Am I missing something?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be using the template_include filter for this:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'wpse_44239_template_include', 1, 1);
function wpse_44239_template_include($template){
    global $wp_query;
    //Do your processing here and define $template as the full path to your alt template.
    return $template;
}
```

`template_redirect` is the action called directly before headers are sent for the output of the rendered template. It's a convenient hook to do 404 redirects, etc... but shouldn't be used for including other templates paths as WordPress does this innately with the 'template_include' filter.

`template_include` and `single_template` hooks deal ONLY with the path of the template used for rendering the content. This is the proper place to adjust a template path.

Update from comment by @ChipBennett:

`single_template` has been [removed as of 3.4.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) Use {posttype}_template instead.

Comment: So, this works, but it turns out the template_redirect and single_template work too. The real problem I determined was that I have a custom admin column sorting function that hooks into the 'request' filter and I wasn't limiting the modification of the $vars variable to only when post type was of a certain type. But, I'm glad to know about the template_include hook. Still not sure what the difference is between template_redirect, template_include and single_template though.

Comment: @anderly I updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: So, what about about single_template? This link (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) says it can be used to adjust the template for a post or page when the single template is called. This is what I'm trying to do. In any case, using either template_include or single_template filters work and appear to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: single_template works the same way except it's called conditionally. This helps to isolate path changes instead of using a hammer filter on the whole site.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help. So, it sounds like single_template is more specific (narrow scope) than template_include?

Comment: That is correct. :)

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: very cool... i didn't know about template_include

Comment: Yep, you answered it (+1). Thanks again!

Comment: Make sure to check the answer as correct so others know what solved your issue. :)

Comment: My bad, thought I had done that. Just marked it as the answer. :)

Comment: FYI, [`single_template` has been removed as of 3.4](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template). Use `{posttype}_template` instead.